# Python function that knows which button engaged it (Tkinter)

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I have placed 9 buttons in a window.  Each button has a picture on it, and I would like the picture to change when the button is clicked.

All the approaches I have seen are too complicated for me to understand (lambda, self, etc), so I would like to know if there is a simple approach.

Here is what I have so far, with three of my buttons:

```
tl=Button(root)
tm=Button(root)
tr=Button(root)

photo1=PhotoImage(file="/Users/apple/Desktop/images Tkinter/arrowhead.gif")
photo2=PhotoImage(file="/Users/apple/Desktop/images Tkinter/arrowhead_plus.gif")

tl.config(image=photo1,width="100",height="100",command=function)
tl.grid(row=1, column=1)

tm.config(image=photo1,width="100",height="100")
tm.grid(row=1, column=2)

tr.config(image=photo1,width="100",height="100")
tr.grid(row=1, column=3)
```

What could the 'function' be? I don't want it to be:

```
def function():
   tl.config(image=photo2,width="100",height="100",command=function)
   tl.grid(row=1, column=1)
```

since this function would only work for this button, and I don't want to write a function for each button.

I hope I have been clear enough. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lambda` key word to do it:

```
tl.config(image=photo2,width="100",height="100",command=lambda: function(1))
```

And so on..
Check [Tkinter Callbacks](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-callbacks.htm) and search for `lambda`.

Comment: Okay but i still have to make a function right ? I still don't get what it should be... I tried this one :
    def function():
       button.config(image=photo2,width="100",height="100")
But it isn't working

Comment: @ArwanCredoz: You need to define function with the button as a paramater: `def function(button):`

Comment: Ooh i see. Thank you very much it's working now that i have this function :  def function(button):
    button.config(image=photo2,width="100",height="100") And instead of having command=lambda: function(1), i replaced the '1' with the name of the button.

Comment: @ArwanCredoz i am glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

`lambda` is your answer :)

If you want to have a general function for all buttons, you have to pass button instance to lambda callback.
Here is a simple example with colors instead of images (tested and it works):

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Button


def function(btn, color):
    btn.config(bg=color)

def main():

    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("250x150+300+300")
    tl = Button(root)
    tm = Button(root)

    tl.config(bg="red", command=lambda: function(tl, 'green'))
    tl.grid(row=1, column=1)

    tm.config(bg="red", command=lambda: function(tm, 'yellow'))
    tm.grid(row=1, column=2)

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When you click the 1st button its background color will change from red to green. Second button will change from red to yellow.

You can apply this to your code to change pictures.

Comment: Thank you for you example, it's going to be useful :)